# Grep command for string doesn't exits only in uncommented line

Tags: grep, make

```
try2:
   set -vn
   set -o pipefail
   set -e
   if grep -v '^#' file.tx | grep -P 'name' file.tx; then \
      echo "    No name"; exit 0;\
      echo " This message is print from file.tx" \
      cat file.tx; fi
```

1) This code above is try to grep if **name** is not exist in **file.tx** then, it will echo **" No Name "**. I want only to grep the word if it not exits in uncommented line but it seems doesn't work.

2) How I want to make if first statement is false, it will go to second statement. The command above seem doesnt't work.

*Note: This code is write in Makefile and the target name is **try2***

Comment: [Please don't post images of text.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/173368)

Comment: I'm uncertain what you mean by that second question. Could you explain? Also change the image to plain text please. It's difficult to read.

Comment: For the second question is, if the string is exits, it will go to second statement wich it "cat file". the above command seem doesn't work

Comment: The first three lines are run in separate shell processes and thus useless. BTW: `set -e` is useless anyway since `make` calls the commands via `sh -ce cmdline` unless you use `make -i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that instead of grepping for `name` in the non-commented data in `file.tx`, you run `grep` against the original file

```
grep -v '^#' file.tx | grep -P 'name' file.tx
                                      ^^^^^^^
                                     will not read from pipe
```

Instead, use

```
grep -v '^#' file.tx | grep -q 'name'
```

i.e., don't make the second `grep` in the pipeline read from the original file.  Also, since you are only interested in the exit status of `grep` (for use in the `if` statement), use it with `-q`.

---

Taking your second question into account, it seem, if I understand correctly, that you want to run `cat file.tx` only if the string `name` is present outside of comments.  In this case you have your logic backwards.

```
if grep -v '^#' file.ex | grep -q 'name'; then
```

This will be true if the string `name` occurs in a non-commented line.  If you want to `cat` the file, then you would need to do it here:

```
if grep -v '^#' file.ex | grep -q 'name'; then \
    cat file.tx; \
else \
    echo 'No name'; \
fi
```

I'm uncertain about the `exit 0` as that has implications for the rest of the Makefile target.  If you want the target to *fail* if `name` is not present, then do `exit 1` after the `echo`, otherwise don't exit at all (unless you have further shell code that you don't want to execute in the same Makefile target).

I'm also noticing your `cd ../..`.  Unless you have a `file.tx` in the current directory *and* in the directory `../..`, the `cat` would fail for you.  You have not mentioned why you step two directory levels up, so I can't say more about this.

Also note that the `cd` will be "undone" as soon as the shell snippet is completed as `make` runs each individual line of a target in a separate shell instance. This also means that the various `set` instructions that you have are run in *separate* shells.

Comment: for second grep, i want non-match string. If, there is no match string "name", then it will print " No Name"

Comment: @daffodil See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, you have a file like this:

> # a comment with the magic word name
>
> some stuff that does not include the magic word

and you want "No name" to be printed. If the first line were uncommented, then "No name" should not be printed.

The following should do that:

```
if grep -v '^#' file.tx | grep -q name; then
       echo "no name"
fi
```

In your code, the second `grep` includes the filename, so it is not looking at the piped input from the first one. Also, since you're not using a Perl regexp, I dropped the `-P`, and I also added `-q` to suppress any output that `grep` might print if something matched.

Comment: for second grep, I don't non-match string. I'd tried grep -Fv but it seem doesn't work.

Comment: I also had tried  grep -I , but it still doesn't work

Comment: correction : I want non-match string. I also had tried  grep -I , but it still doesn't work